# Jquery code error: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple problem that I cannot find the answer to. I have made a jsfiddle of the problem.

I have this Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display-feedback-form').off('click').on('click', function(){
        $('#feedback_form').show();
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle with an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJW34/)

Why am I getting this error? Jquery is loaded correctly on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you're loading jQuery correctly, but you're loading jQuery 1.6.4.

[$.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) weren't added until jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

`.on()` and `.off()` weren't introduced until jQuery 1.7. You are loading 1.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) and [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in jQuery 1.6.4. Until 1.7 there is no `.off()` and `.on()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display-feedback-form').die('click').live('click', function(){
        $('#feedback_form').show();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kJW34/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#display-feedback-form').click(function(){
        $('#feedback_form').show();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJW34/6/)